# Setting UILabel font size, moves text left of its frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm configuring a UITableViewCell.

```
    mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8, 226, 14)] autorelease];
    mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
    mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];        
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
```

The problem is when setting the text font size the text is displayed with a negative left margin, so it starts before the X coordinate in the frame.

If I comment the font size instruction:

```
    mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
```

The text is displayed in place.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line

```
mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: You are right, thought I have tested that. I cannot even remember why I add that line code.